# Is there a way to have leading zero in result when using string native function in Sybase?

Tags: string, configuration, sap-ase

I am using the string native function in Sybase to convert numeric datatypes to string.
When the numeric number is between 0 and 1, the leading zero won't show up. I know I could concatenate the leading zero, but I'm looking for another approach.

Is there any other solution like a configuration I am missing in sybase ?

```
select string(0.86); ---- output .86 (missing leading zero, expecting 0.86)
select string(1.86); ---- output 1.86
```

I expect the output 0.86 in the results window, but instead I get .86

Comment: The output formatting is not related to database engine but to the client that is using for the connection. What client application is used?

Comment: `string` is not a valid function, use `select convert(varchar, 0.86)` or `select str(0.86, 10, 2)` instead